# Deploy mod_wsgi in CENTOS 7

Tags: python, django

Ya realice la configuración de mi apache y el wsgi pero envia el siguiente error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prueba'

A que creen que se deba este error?

Comment: No existe el modulo "prueba", o estas importando mal o dicho modulo no existe.

Comment: eso ya lo se, pero estoy configurando un servidor CentOS con apache, wsgi y django lo configuro y ese mensaje es el que me manda eh visto algunos tutoriales y si funciona correctamente hasta con el wsgi por default no se a que se deba esto.